# How to use Native Node Modules on a React, ES6, Electron App?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, electron

I have a React, Electron app that I wish to be able to access native node modules from the ES6 compiled (using Babel and Webpack).

For example, when I try to require the "fs" node module to access the filesystem I get the following error.

```
ERROR in ./src/app.js Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'fs' in C:\Users\Propietario-1\Documents\GitHub\AMPLI @ ./src/app.js 1:358-371
```

But when I required this from a "none compiled" js file it works. I can access the "fs" module.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update (2016-08-28):**

I ended up requiring the `fs` module in a script tag on the index.html that calls the bundled script. It works!

```
<script>
const fs = require('fs');

require('bundle.js');
</script>
```

After doing this the `fs` becomes a global variable available to all scripts in the `bundle.js`. Just make sure to edit your linter options to avoid overwriting it or `undef` errors.

Comment: Are you trying to access the `fs` module in the browser?

Comment: did you try `npm i fs` ?

Comment: Please post your *updated answer* section as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 7):

Electron runs as two processes: the main node process and the renderer process, a bit like a conventional web browser client and server relationship. The renderer process cannot use node modules that are unsuitable for the browser (e.g. `fs`), because basically it is a browser.

Two methods are provided to communicate between the renderer process and the main process: `ipcRenderer` and `remote`. For simple tasks, remote is easier. To use the `fs` module from your webpacked react project, in the renderer process:

```
var fs = require('electron').remote.require('fs');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not know about "remote". However, it still does not seem to work. I required `fs` as you said but it still says that it cannot resolve the module. I opted to require the `fs` module in the index.html file that calls the bundled script as a global variable `const fs = require('fs')` in the meantime. It works.

Comment: @mccleanp You saved my effing sanity!! I've been trying to get `odbc` working in an Electron app for 3 days. I have about 100 browser tabs open and this is the first time I've heard about `remote`. And it works. Brilliantly. Looking at your profile, this is your only answer on StackOverflow. Well, I just want to say thank you for taking the time to answer this question. You saved me from losing my mind. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up requiring the `fs` module in a script tag on the index.html that calls the bundled script. It works!

```
<script>
const fs = require('fs');

require('bundle.js');
</script>
```

After doing this the `fs` becomes a global variable avaible to all scripts in the `bundle.js`. Just make sure to edit your linter options to avoid overwriting it or `undef` errors.